# Browser automatically closing list tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, html-lists

I'm trying to make a html list using jQuery but browsers are prematurely closing my ul tag and li tags.

As a simple example, I tried to make this list:

> - Hello
> - How are you?

So I wrote the code:

```
$("#test").append("<ul>");
$("#test").append("<li>");
$("#test").append("Hello");
$("#test").append("</li>");
$("#test").append("<li>");
$("#test").append("How are you?");
$("#test").append("</li>");
$("#test").append("</ul>");
```

But the code resulted in:

> •
>   Hello
>   •
>   How are you?

I know that instead I could simply write:

```
$("#test").append("<ul><li>Hello</li><li>How are you?</li></ul>");
```

but my project requires the code to be on several lines.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/greyshark7/99764x9h/

Comment: `.append` does not work this way - you need to pass it the full HTML code for an element, you can not “append” a starting and a closing _tag_ in separate steps, that just makes no sense in DOM terms. So `<li>Hello</li>` is the smallest “append unit” you can get away with here.

Comment: Can you not try `document.createElement('ul')` and so on? its also faster than jQuery converting your html string into an element(`$("<ul></ul>")`)

Comment: You're not "append"ing html like you would with a `StringBuilder`, you're appending DOM nodes.  So when you append `<ul>` you're actually appending `<ul></ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid appending just parts, cause jquery will close them automaticly.

So there are two easy solution which come in my mind:

The first would be to build the append string:

```
var try = "";
try = try + "<ul>";
try = try + "<li>";
try = try + "Hello";
//And so on
$("#test").append(try);
```

Or something like this: 
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hftps50p/)

You can get further(and avoid many ids) by selecting the to append child with nth:child. Or like in the other answer by saving it in a variable.

Answer (score 3):

**try like this**

```
var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
ul.append('<li>hello</li>');
ul.append('<li>how r u</li>');
ul.append('<li>fine</li>');
$("#test").append(ul);
```